# "Flat links", a reference request

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

A hyperbolic link is  one whose  complement  admits  a hyperbolic metric. 
Hyperbolic links, and especially   hyperbolic  knots,  are quite  popular these days.  However,    I am  currently interested in  links whose  complement  admits  a  flat (i.e. locally euclidean) metric. If I got it right, the major difference from the hyperbolic case is the existence 
(at least, I want for it to exist) of a natural compactification. This compactification  makes the 3-sphere into an  Alexandrov  space with conical singularities along the components of the link, or something like this.  Is there such a construction somewhere in the literature?

[EDIT] I think I need to clarify this a bit. What I want is a metric on ${\mathbb S}^3$ such that

1) The metric is flat outside of the link.

2) Each component of the link has a neighborhood isometric to a product of a conical point by  ${\mathbb S}^1$.

(So, if it is a ``negative'' conical point, then it won't be an Alexandrov  space.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical reference for this sort of thing is:

*Cooper, Daryl; Hodgson, Craig D.; Kerckhoff, Steven P.*, [**Three-dimensional orbifolds and cone-manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2969/msjmemoirs/005010000), MSJ Memoirs. 5. Tokyo: Mathematical Society of Japan (MSJ). ix, 170 p. (2000). [ZBL0955.57014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0955.57014).

(available for free on Daryl Cooper's web page at UCSB).